# Как в JpaRepository сделать запрос для выбора всех записей только с условием in?

Tags: spring

Как в JpaRepository сделать запрос для выбора всех записей только с условием in?

```
select * from table
where field in (1, 2, ...)
order by field2
```

Пробовал так, но сам репозиторий не может сгенерироваться

```
findAllByFieldInOrderByField2
```

Comment: в параметры метода что передаёте? и не проще ли написать @Query для сложного запроса, чем ломать голову над тем как там правильно написать метод

Comment: Это и явилось решением